# Change status of bugs associated with build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to change the status of multiple bugs associated with a specific build?

For example: when a run my `Test` build definition, I would like all of the bugs associated with that build to change their status from `Fixed` to `Waiting for retest`

Answer (score 0):

Not without building a custom Build Activity, which can do the update you want based on the [Associated Workitems and the Client Object Model](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/). Or through a server side [`ISubscriber` implementation](http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/) that acts on the [Build Completed event](http://intovsts.net/2012/02/12/managing-builds-through-the-build-quality-value/).